# init a class with "diamond" heritage in python

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

I have the following python code :

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("init A")
        self.N = 0

class B1(A):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("init B1")
        super().__init__()
        self.N = 1

class B2(A):
    def __init__(self, Q) -> None:
        print("init B2")
        super().__init__()
        self.Q = Q

class C(B1, B2):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("init C")
        super().__init__()
```

There is a main class `A`, then two classes `B1` and `B2` both inheriting `A`, and then a class `C` inheriting `B1` and `B2` :

```
       +-----+
       |  A  |
       +-----+
     /         \
    /           \
+------+    +------+
|  B1  |    |  B2  |
+------+    +------+
    \           /
     \         /
       +-----+
       |  C  |
       +-----+
```

As you can see, the number of arguments for the initialization of `B1` and `B2` is not the same : `B2` need a value of `Q` while `B1` doesn't.

As it is, when I try to create an instance of `C` with the code `c = C()` I get the following error :

```
init C
init B1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AA.py", line 26, in <module>
    c = C()
  File "AA.py", line 24, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "AA.py", line 12, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Q'
```

I did not manage to find a way to fix this : in the initialization of `C`, initialize the two parent classes separately. I tried `super(B1).__init__(...)` or `B1.__init__(...)`, unsuccessfully...

Comment: Could you just make B1 and/or B2's be: `def __init__(self, Q=None) -> None:` so that it'll take Q, but not need it, and use it if necesary?

Comment: Use of `super()`, diamond inheritance, varying parameter lists in subclasses; pick any two, all three simply don't work together.

Comment: The general advice is to use *keyword arguments* when instantiating a class in such a hierarchy, and write each `__init__` to accept arbitrary keywords arguments to pass on to `super().__init__`. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the classes to make cooperative inheritance work properly.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init_(**kwargs)
        print("init A")
        self.N = 0

class B1(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("init B1")
        super().__init_(**kwargs)
        self.N = 1

class B2(A):
    def __init__(self, *, Q, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("init B2")
        super().__init_(**kwargs)
        self.Q = Q

class C(B1, B2):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("init C")
        super().__init_(**kwargs)


c = C(Q=3)
```

All `__init__` (even `A`, to allow it to work with other base classes) functions accept arbitrary keyword arguments. Any keyword argument that isn't used to set an explicitly declared parameter will be passed up the chain. Eventually, all keyword arguments should be accounted for in this fashion before `super().__init__` invokes `object.__init__`.

When you call `C.__init__`, the `Q` argument will be passed first to `B2.__init__`, which will pass it to `B1.__init__`, which uses it and passes the now-empty `kwargs` on to `A.__init__`, and ultimately to `object.__init__`.